# Wordpress - Get custom post type posts on index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, post-format

I made a custom post type for my theme and I want the content to be displayed just like a normal post on the index page.

My code on index.php looks like this

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <div class="container">

            <?php

                if( have_posts() ):

                    while( have_posts() ): the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );



                    endwhile;

                endif;

             ?>

        </div><!-- .container -->

    </main>
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

I have a different style for every post format and it's saved in content-"post-format-name".php. But if I save a post on my custom post type with a post format of "Standard" it still doesn't show up.

Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Custom post type displaying

By default only posts are retrieved from database using main query and registering custom post type change nothing on this.

According to [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types_in_the_Main_Query) you must hook into `pre_get_posts` action like this

```
// Show posts of 'post', 'page' and 'movie' post types on home page
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'movie' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

### Standard post format

Your problem with standard post format is that the `get_post_format` function returns `FALSE` for default format ([documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format)). You must use some if statement to sanitise this case.

Comment: `return $query` is not necessary in actions. `return $variable_name` is only needed in filters

Comment: I agree. Code is not main but from documentation.